# How do I find an object in a redux array using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Here is my slice.ts file.

```js
interface iItem {
  Category: string;
  Id: string;
}

interface iDataState {
  Items: Array<iItem>;
}

const initialState: iDataState = {
  Items: [],
};


reducers: {
  updateItem: (state, action: PayloadAction<iItem>) => {
    console.log(state.Items);
  }
}
```

Every time I run `dispatch(updateItem(data));` in a component, I see *Proxy(Array) {0: {…}}* in the console.

How can I update an item in `Items` if I can't access `Items` to search for the item to update?

Comment: _"if I can't access Items"_ Are you sure you can't? What happens if you log `state.Items[0]`? Do you get an item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using redux toolkit

Rtk is wrapping your reducer function with [immerjs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/produce) (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers).

This allow you to compute you next state by mutating the current state.

Immer allow this by wrapping the state in a proxy which reimplement all the method of Array like `find`.

If you want to log the wrapped state for debugging sake, you can use the function `current` exported by immer
`console.log(current(state))`;

Comment: current is exactly what I needed.

current(state.Items) works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Redux-Toolkit (RTK) implements Immer.js under-the-hood, which allows you to write ***mutable*** state updates instead being forced to use the older ***immutable*** state update, e.g. shallow copying all the state that isn't being updated. In RTK you can just directly mutate the state that you need to update.

Example, updating the 6th element of the `Items` array:

```js
reducers: {
  updateItem: (state, action: PayloadAction<iItem>) => {
    state.Items[5] = action.payload;
  }
}
```

The `state` is a mutable draft, so if `state.Items` is an array, then you can use any Array methods on it.

When you are "mutating" the state you aren't actually mutating the `state` object, but rather a draft copy of it. This is the `proxy` object that you are seeing in the console log. If you want to console log the actual "current" state value in the reducer function RTK re-exports the [`current`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#current) function from the immer library. Use this to wrap the draft state.

> The `current` function from the `immer` library, which takes a
> snapshot of the current state of a draft and finalizes it (but without
> freezing). Current is a great utility to print the `current` state
> during debugging, and the output of current can also be safely leaked
> outside the producer.

Example:

```js
import { current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

...

reducers: {
  updateItem: (state, action: PayloadAction<iItem>) => {
    ...

    console.log(current(state.Items));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The items look correct, it just looks like they are wrapped in a JS [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), which is used by many libraries these days. Describing Proxies is the beyond the scope of this answer, but in general you should be able to treat `state.Items` as a normal array like you expect. You can `find`, `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, and everything else you need to find and update items in the array.